# Algorithm to determine if cheese slices can be reassembled into a complete block

Tags: python, backtracking

I am trying to write a program that determines whether a set of cheese slices, which are rectangular and all one millimeter thick, can be assembled back into a complete block and in what order. Essentially, the problem is to check if a given set of rectangular pieces can be arranged in a way that forms a solid block of cheese. Can anyone suggest an algorithm or approach to solve this problem? I am programming in Python, but I am open to suggestions in other languages as well. Here's my code so far:

```
import os

# Function to import the file
def importFile(file):
    slices = []
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        number_of_slices = float(lines[0])
        for line in range(1, len(lines)):
            slices.append(lines[line].strip().split(" "))
        for i in range(0, len(slices)):
            for j in range(0,2):
                slices[i][j] = float(slices[i][j])
    return number_of_slices, slices
# Main function to determine the solution
def backtracking(file):
    # Import the file and declare variables
    imported = importFile(file)
    number_of_slices = imported[0]
    slices = imported[1]

    # Create a new cheese block
    cheese = cheeseBlock()
    # Add the first slice to the cheese block and remove it from the list of slices
    cheese.addSlice(slices[0], "FRONT")
    slices.pop(0)
    # List to keep track of which slices have been checked
    checkedSlices = [[], []]
    # Repeat until all slices are added to the cheese block
    while len(cheese.addedSlices) < number_of_slices:
        # Select the next slice to add (must fit on the cheese block and not be in the checked list of the last level)
        nextSlice = None
        for slice in slices:
            if cheese.checkSlice(slice) != None and slice not in checkedSlices[-1]:
                nextSlice = slice
                break
        if nextSlice == None:
            # Add the last slice back to the list of slices
            slices.append(cheese.addedSlices[-1])
            # Remove the last entry from the checked list
            checkedSlices.pop()
            # Add the slice to the checked list of the last level
            checkedSlices[-1].append(cheese.addedSlices[-1])
            # Remove the slice from the cheese block
            cheese.removeSlice()
            # If the cheese block is empty, choose a new start slice that is not in the checked list
            if cheese.addedSlices == []:
                for slice in slices:
                    if slice not in checkedSlices[-1]:
                        cheese.addSlice(slice, "TOP")
                        checkedSlices += [[]]
                        break
                # If no start slice is found, there is no solution
                if cheese.addedSlices == []:
                    return None
        # If a slice is found
        else:
            # Add a new level to the checked list
            checkedSlices += [[]]
            # Add the slice to the cheese block
            position = cheese.checkSlice(nextSlice)
            cheese.addSlice(nextSlice, position)
            # Remove the slice from the list of remaining slices
            slices.remove(nextSlice)

    # Output the order of slices added to the cheese block (reverse order corresponds to order of cutting)
    return cheese.addedSlices

# Class for the cheese block
class cheeseBlock():
    def __init__(self):
        # List of slices added to the cheese block (initially empty)
        self.addedSlices = []
        # Dimensions of the cheese block in millimeters
        self.height = 0 # Height
        self.width = 0  # Width
        self.length = 0 # Depth

    # Method to add a slice to the cheese block and adjust the dimensions accordingly
    def addSlice(self, slice, position):
        if self.addedSlices == []:
            self.addedSlices
            self.addedSlices += [slice]
            self.height = slice[1]
            self.width = slice[0]
            self.length += 1
        else:
            self.addedSlices += [slice]
            if position == "TOP":
                self.height += 1
            elif position == "SIDE":
                self.width += 1
            elif position == "FRONT":
                self.length += 1

    # Method to remove the last slice added to the cheese block and adjust the dimensions accordingly
    def removeSlice(self):
        position = self.checkSlice(self.addedSlices[-1])
        self.addedSlices.pop()
        if position == "TOP":
            self.height -= 1
        elif position == "SIDE":
            self.width -= 1
        elif position == "FRONT":
            self.length -= 1

    # Method to check if a given slice can be added to the cheese block and if so, at which position
    def checkSlice(self, slice):
        if (self.width == slice[0] and self.length == slice[1]) or (self.width == slice[1] and self.length == slice[0]):
            position = "TOP"
        elif (self.length == slice[0] and self.height == slice[1]) or (self.length == slice[1] and self.height == slice[0]):
            position = "SIDE"
        elif (self.width == slice[0] and self.height == slice[1]) or (self.width == slice[1] and self.height == slice[0]):
            position = "FRONT"
        else:
            return None
        return position

filename = "kaese5.txt"
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, filename)
solution = backtracking(file_path)

if solution == None:
   print("The given slices cannot be used to form a block of cheese that contains all slices")
else:
   solution.reverse()
   print("The slices were cut in the following order to form the cheese block:")
   for slice in solution:
      print(slice[0], slice[1])
```

And example can be found under the following link:https://bwinf.de/fileadmin/bundeswettbewerb/41/kaese5.txt. Here, the first line reresents the total number of slices, whereas in the following lines one could read the size of each slice.
The code above uses a backtracking algorithm to solve a problem of cutting cheese slices into a rectangular block.
The code defines two functions, importFile(file), backtracking(file), and the class cheeseBlock(), to import data from a file, solve the problem using backtracking, and represent the cheese block, respectively.
The backtracking(file) function is the main function that applies the backtracking algorithm to determine the order of slices to cut to form a rectangular block of cheese containing all the slices.
The cheeseBlock() class is used to keep track of the cheese dimensions and the order of slices added to the block.
The final solution is printed to the console in the order of the slices cut.

The question: How can I increase the performance of that algorithm? Do I have to use another approach? I want it to work for up to 1.5 Million slices.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot adding the question. I've just edited my post.

Comment: Syntax error line 91

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the indent in the last if-else-statement. Try to format the statement again.

Comment: All statements in the class definitions starting with line 91 must me indented 4 spaces. Please fix the code in your post.

Comment: Also  on line 124 File should be filename.

Comment: I've edited the code so it compiles, runs and produces what appears to be valid output. The edits are pending review by a third party.

Comment: @MichaelSchreiber You should fix the indentation in the code here rather than requesting us to do it for you.